# Convert python code to byte code to binary and print out the binary in a list

Tags: python, binary, bytecode

```py
import dis, struct

def func():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = a + b
    print(c)

code = dis.Bytecode(func)
packed = struct.pack('B' * code.size, *code)

binary_code = ''
for b in packed:
    binary_code += bin(b)[2:].zfill(8)

list_code = ''
for i in range(0, len(binary_code), 8):
    string_code += chr(int(binary_code[i:i+8], 2))

print(list_code)
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Pies\Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    packed = struct.pack('B' * code.size, *code)
AttributeError: 'Bytecode' object has no attribute 'size'
```

When converting to size instead of `len` I get the opposite code object has no `len`.

```py
packed = struct.pack('B' * len(code), *code)
```

> TypeError: object of type 'Bytecode' has no len()

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `packed` to contain? The actual bytecode for the function, as raw bytes (i.e. as it would appear within the `.pyc` file)?

Comment: Also, what are `list_code` and `string_code` supposed to be? In particular, I see a line `list_code = ''`, but I don't see anything else that would change the value of `list_code`.

Answer (score 2):

> AttributeError: 'Bytecode' object has no attribute 'size'

Well, yes: as the [documentation will tell you](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.Bytecode), there isn't any `.size` to access. Similarly, `len` is also not supported.

This is because the `Bytecode` that you get back from `dis.Bytecode(func)` is **not a raw sequence of bytes, instructions, or anything else**.

It is a **wrapper around** the function's "code object", which is in turn a wrapper around the actual bytecode.

We don't need or want the wrapper from `dis`. We can directly access the function's code object:

```
>>> # Python 2.x
>>> # func.co_code
>>> # Python 3.x
>>> func.__code__
<code object func at 0x7f6b8aaf5d40, file "<stdin>", line 1>
```

And verify that this is the same thing that the `dis` module finds:

```
>>> func.__code__ is dis.Bytecode(func).codeobj
True
```

To get the actual bytecode from this code object, we need one more step:

```
>>> func.__code__.co_code
b'd\x01}\x00d\x02}\x01|\x00|\x01\x17\x00}\x02t\x00|\x02\x83\x01\x01\x00d\x00S\x00'
```

Notice that **this is already a `bytes` object**, i.e., the raw bytes of data that would be written into a `.pyc` file. Therefore, there is no reason to use `struct` to do any processing. It is already "packed".

---

If, instead, we want a list of `dis.Instruction` objects (which represent individual codes in the function's bytecode) - yes, we can "unpack" these using `*code`; the `dis.Bytecode` **is** iterable, even though it doesn't have a `.size` or a `len` (and can't be indexed).

In order to work with the actual sequence of `Instruction`s more easily, we can explicitly make a `list` of them first:

```
>>> code = dis.Bytecode(func)
>>> # Another way: 
>>> # [*code]
>>> list(code) 
[Instruction(opname='LOAD_CONST', opcode=100, arg=1, argval=10, argrepr='10', offset=0, starts_line=2, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='STORE_FAST', opcode=125, arg=0, argval='a', argrepr='a', offset=2, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='LOAD_CONST', opcode=100, arg=2, argval=20, argrepr='20', offset=4, starts_line=3, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='STORE_FAST', opcode=125, arg=1, argval='b', argrepr='b', offset=6, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=0, argval='a', argrepr='a', offset=8, starts_line=4, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=1, argval='b', argrepr='b', offset=10, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='BINARY_ADD', opcode=23, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=12, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='STORE_FAST', opcode=125, arg=2, argval='c', argrepr='c', offset=14, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='LOAD_GLOBAL', opcode=116, arg=0, argval='print', argrepr='print', offset=16, starts_line=5, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=2, argval='c', argrepr='c', offset=18, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='CALL_FUNCTION', opcode=131, arg=1, argval=1, argrepr='', offset=20, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='POP_TOP', opcode=1, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=22, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='LOAD_CONST', opcode=100, arg=0, argval=None, argrepr='None', offset=24, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), Instruction(opname='RETURN_VALUE', opcode=83, arg=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=26, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)]
```

These objects will **not work** with `struct` packing, because again they are wrappers around the raw data (designed to give you more information). They are also **not designed** to give back the corresponding underlying raw bytes - that will take more work, which involves understanding how the bytecode works at a low level. It will be much easier to work with the function's code object directly

---

Note also that the contents of the function's bytecode are **not enough** to be able to recreate the function. For example, some of these instructions are used to load hard-coded data (constants in the code, such as integer literals). These are stored separately. The function object also keeps a reference to its global-variable context.

Comment: The rest of the processing you want to do is broken, and does not really make any sense. Converting to those `zfill`ed `bin` strings and then to `int` just gives you back the numeric values that are already directly stored in the `bytes` object; converting each byte value using `chr` can be done more simply by just `.decode`ing the bytes as `iso-8859-1` encoded text. However, this **will give you garbage text**, because the bytecode **does not represent text** and is not intended to be printable like that.

Answer (score 0):

text = 'Hello World'

ascii_codes = [ord(c) for c in text]

print(ascii_codes)

binary_numbers = [bin(c)[2:] for c in ascii_codes]

print(binary_numbers)

text = ''.join([chr(int(b, 2)) for b in binary_numbers])

print(text)